# C# The name "..." does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
namespace ICNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your Singapore IC starting with T:");
            string ICnumber = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            int totalsum = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++)
            {
                int number = ICnumber.IndexOf(ICnumber, k);
                int digitsum = 0;
                if (k is 1)
                    digitsum = number * 2;
                if (k is 2)
                    digitsum = number * 7;
                if (k is 3)
                    digitsum = number * 6;
                if (k is 4)
                    digitsum = number * 5;
                if (k is 5)
                    digitsum = number * 4;
                if (k is 6)
                    digitsum = number * 3;
                if (k is 7)
                    digitsum = number * 2;
                totalsum = totalsum + digitsum;
            }
            int validcheck = (totalsum + 4) % 11;
            string Validcheck = Convert.ToString(validcheck);
            int letter = ICnumber.IndexOf(ICnumber, 8);
            string Letter = Convert.ToString(letter);
            if (Validcheck == "0" && Letter == "J")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck == "1" && Letter =="Z")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck == "2" && Letter =="I")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck == "3" && Letter =="H")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck == "4" && Letter =="G")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck == "5" && Letter =="F")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck == "6" && Letter =="E")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck =="7" && Letter =="D")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck =="8" && Letter =="C")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck =="9" && Letter =="B")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            if (Validcheck =="10" && Letter =="A")
            {
            string validity = "Valid";
            }
            else
            {
            string validity = "False";
            }
            string Validity = validity;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that i cant use the variable validity?

Comment: You cannot use `validity` outside the braces because their scope is within the brace.

Comment: @Eldho No, that's incorrect. It's not declared even once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because validity is local to the scope of the if's/else's. You can only use a variable inside of the curly brackets you define it in (by writing the datatype in front of the name). This is how to declare the variable in the function scope and then just reference if inside the if's and else's

```
namespace ICNumber
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your Singapore IC starting with T:");
        string ICnumber = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        int totalsum = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++)
        {
            int number = ICnumber.IndexOf(ICnumber, k);
            int digitsum = 0;
            if (k  == 1)
                digitsum = number * 2;
            if (k  == 2)
                digitsum = number * 7;
            if (k == 3)
                digitsum = number * 6;
            if (k  == 4)
                digitsum = number * 5;
            if (k  == 5)
                digitsum = number * 4;
            if (k  == 6)
                digitsum = number * 3;
            if (k  == 7)
                digitsum = number * 2;
            totalsum = totalsum + digitsum;
        }
        int validcheck = (totalsum + 4) % 11;
        string Validcheck = Convert.ToString(validcheck);
        int letter = ICnumber.IndexOf(ICnumber, 8);
        string Letter = Convert.ToString(letter);
        string validity=""; //declare the variable here
        if (Validcheck == "0" && Letter == "J")
        {
            validity = "Valid";//remove the keyword string. If you use the keyword you create a new variable (different from the one above)
        }
        else if (Validcheck == "1" && Letter =="Z")
        {
            validity = "Valid"; //keep on referencing the variable everywhere you need it
        }
        else if (Validcheck == "2" && Letter =="I")
        {
            validity = "Valid";
        }
        else if (Validcheck == "3" && Letter =="H")
       .
       .
       .
```

Comment: Im not sure how `k is 1` compiles for OP

Comment: `k is 1` doesn't compile. It also does not make sense to use so many `if`s instead of `if-else`

Answer (score 0):

Variables in C# have block scope. If you declare a variable inside the block body of an `if` statement, it will only exist there.

Declare your variable outside the `if` statements. There is also a logic error in your code - the `else` at the end is attached only to the last `if`, so in order for your approach to work, you would need to use `else if` for the intermediate `if`s:

```
string validity = null;
if (Validcheck == "0" && Letter == "J")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
else if (Validcheck == "1" && Letter =="Z")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
else if (Validcheck == "2" && Letter =="I")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
else if (Validcheck == "3" && Letter =="H")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
else if (Validcheck == "4" && Letter =="G")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
else if (Validcheck == "5" && Letter =="F")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
// .... etc.
else {
    validity = "False"
}
string Validity = validity;
```

All of those `if` statements are also extremely redundant and could be replaced with a single `if` statement with one large condition.

Comment: "could be replaced with a single if statement with one large condition." are you kidding? That'd be the longest if statement ever

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it would be far better than using 12 separate `if` statements, though there are better options than both of these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable validity outside of your if blocks.  Since C# has block level scoping, each of your `string validity =...` statements is actually declaring a different variable named validity that only exists within that scope.  When you're declaring the validity variable alongside validCheck:

```
int validcheck = (totalsum + 4) % 11;
string Validcheck = Convert.ToString(validcheck);
string validity = string.Empty;
```

And then updating each of the assignments to not include the typename:

```
if (Validcheck =="7" && Letter =="D")
{
    validity = "Valid";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You keep declaring the variable `validity` all the time. Declare it once then assign it. Also make it `bool`

I'd also consider a pre declared array or dictionary of valid combinations so you can just look up what you have in a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Good advice but does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare string validity 1st before :

```
string validity = "";
if (Validcheck == "0" && Letter == "J")
{
validity = "Valid"
}...
```